# Where to ask question about phpMyAdmin?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about quirky behavior with phpMyAdmin and it not showing notifications about updates and I'm not sure which Stack Exchange site this would best fit on.

[phpMyAdmin's support page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/) says:

> Questions directly related to phpMyAdmin should be asked on stackoverflow."

However, it's not a coding question but more of an odd behavior/configuration question. Would [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) be a better fit or is there somewhere else it could go?

Comment: There are some answers on [m.dba](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/should-dba-be-the-primary-phpmyadmin-usage-support-channel) and [m.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263603/the-phpmyadmin-support-page-points-to-stackoverflow-com-and-serverfault-com-as-t) that may be helpful.

Comment: The sentence right after the one you quoted says "Questions about server issues (web server configuration, "404 - Not Found" error, etc), should be asked on serverfault.com."

Comment: @SomethingDark - I'm a little leery since I'm getting no actual errors. phpMyAdmin simply isn't notifying me of updates when in past versions it has.

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues

Comment: 2) - Stack overflow is a good place to look for something like this, or DBA

Comment: Server Fault is quite strict about the questions asked there, and *will* not hesitate to downvote & close your question if it is not firmly about a professional system (I asked a question once about gameservers when I was a professional gameserver host, question got downvoted + closed when it was on-topic; just not 'professional' in their eyes).

Comment: Looking through the questions tagged, my quick sampling revealed most of them have nothing to do with phpMyAdmin at all, but rather database-related errors thrown by php. I think someone should reach out to the phpMyAdmin people and ask them to modify their language, and not link to StackOverflow but rather a more appropriate stack.... if any.

Comment: @ChrisBaker - Well volunteered!

Comment: @j08691 Please include the exact question you'd like to ask. I suspect that it's not really pertinent on any SE site because I think you're asking something like 'Why is phpMyAdmin not notifying me of [X] updates in version Y when it did in previous versions?", which isn't *necessarily* something that anyone other than the phpMyAdmin developers can answer. And depending on what those updates pertain to – e.g. database administration – your question could be on-topic on a variety of (and potentially even multiple) SE sites.

Comment: [The question on Webmasters SE.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/85452/6511)

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion questions regarding PHPMyAdmin should be asked on [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).
From their [Help > Topics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> This site is for anything that relates to owning, running, or administering your own website.

**Don't** ask your question on Server Fault; it will be closed as Server Fault is for *Network & Computer Systems Administration* in *professional environments*.

Comment: I'm not sure if PHPMyAdmin is strictly a webmasters tool, it is more of a DBA tool if the question is not in the context programming

Comment: Yeah, it's mainly DBA, which is on-topic for Webmasters.SE. Questions for MySQL programming are probably best asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Obviously there is some overlap, but my vote is on wm.se as well.

Comment: It's up on WSE so we'll see how that goes.

Comment: I'm a mod as WE.se. We're good with having these questions there.

Comment: There are upvoted questions on Server Fault about phpMyAdmin. [Here's one.](http://serverfault.com/q/615550/40350) It's entirely possible – even likely – that j08691's question is on-topic at Webmasters SE but that's not enough to say that it definitely "should" be asked there (and not on another SE site). phpMyAdmin is just an admin tool for MySQL databases; it's not inherently tied to a website.

Comment: @KennyEvitt See the comment above yours, a moderator of Webmasters.SE confirmed that it's the site to ask the question on. The question you linked to on SF is a rare one to find on there, and certainly should be used as evidence that similar questions should not be asked there

Answer (score 0):

## phpMyAdmin Questions in General

Questions about phpMyAdmin are, in general, absolutely on-topic on Stack Overflow. That said, it's possible another Stack Exchange site is more appropriate, but which site that might be is entirely dependent on the specifics of the actual question being asked. Some other potentially appropriate sites:

- [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)
- [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) [[as suggested by one of the phpMyAdmin contributors](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/issues/15#issuecomment-143804971)]

But keep in mind that, apart from appropriateness, there are large differences in the size of the expert audience that is likely capable of answering these questions.

- The DBAs on the DBA SE site are probably heavily tilted towards more-traditional DB tools – [there are only 166 questions tagged [phpmyadmin]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin).
- Server Fault's users are mostly professional network and systems admins – [there are only 23 questions tagged [phpmyadmin]](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin).
- Webmasters is a good fit, but it's a relatively small SE site – [there are only 45 questions tagged [phpmyadmin]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin).
- Web Applications is probably the least good fit as it's geared more towards 'general user' web applications, not technical tools – [there are no questions tagged [phpmyadmin] and only three results for "phpmyadmin"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=phpmyadmin)

## Your phpMyAdmin Question

Without knowing more, I'd say your question should be asked on a mailing list or forum, ideally for phypMyAdmin itself. I have a strong hunch that your question pertains to a bug or other broken functionality (e.g. the phpMyAdmin website itself). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there is either a suitable mailing list or forum for your question, at least not officially.

Based on what you've written (and [your actual question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/85452/6511)) – "more of an odd behavior/configuration question" – I think you should submit an issue against [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues).

In fact, I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/issues/15) pertaining to this question on [the GitHub repo for their website](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website) and a contributor made two changes ([this one](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/commit/217e802efa773e54a7206ea006daa5a10ccaa578) and [this one](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/website/commit/e1e8006dc760e2f7fc8db41c52c34ccf3d6992bd)) to the Support page on their website that clarifies where users should ask for help.

Here's the latest version of the relevant text on [the support page](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/):

> ### Types of questions and where to ask
>
> - How do I? — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/phpmyadmin/info)
> - I got this error, why? — [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/phpmyadmin/info)
> - I got this web server error (like "404 - Not Found") — [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/tags/phpmyadmin) or [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/phpmyadmin)
> - I got this error on the current stable version and I'm sure it's a bug — Please file an [issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues)
> - I have an idea/request — Please file an [issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues)
> - I have a question about the code itself — Use our [developers@phpmyadmin.net](https://lists.phpmyadmin.net/mailman/listinfo/developers) mailing list

Comment: I disagree. A mailing list might be a good idea in certain situations, but you won't have the support available if you posted it on an SE site, for example [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/); it's *exactly* for this type of thing.

Comment: @cybermonkey The SE sites aren't support forums. And it seems like the OP is asking a question that's probably too specific for SE sites anyways, i.e. "[Why phpMyAdmin] simply isn't notifying me of updates when in past versions it has".

Comment: Yes, I know that (*please stop treating me like a subordinate [from your other comments], we're equal*). If the OP asked their question, I'm *pretty sure* they wouldn't be stupid enough to leave out stuff related to the issue such as error logs.

Comment: @cybermonkey FWIW, I don't see any comments from Kenny that could be construed as treating you like a subordinate.