# Is it intended that I can delete my comment that resulted from a duplicate vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, deleted-comments

When flagging a question as duplicate, a comment appears, notifying the OP about a possible duplicate.

I noticed that it is possible to delete that comment, even without removing the duplicate flag itself. Is that intended? If so, what is the purpose of it?

E.g. for this question, I voted to close as duplicate of [Where to ask question about PhpMyAdmin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306866/where-to-ask-question-about-phpmyadmin) and then deleted the comment.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem, even lesser so if future dupe votes result in the comment being re-added by the next user. The comment already gets auto-deleted when the question is closed as a dupe.

Comment: @KevinB: I didn't say that's a problem, I just wanted to know how to use it.

Comment: how to use... what. i'm confused now.

Comment: You can also delete the comment if you find out (either by mistake or via OP's edits) the flagged dupe isn't exactly so. Helps to prevent needless discussion and you can just let the flag reviewers handle the error

Comment: I don't think these comments should be generated anyway. It's semantically the wrong system to use to present that information. That you can arbitrarily write, edit and delete such comments is just one example of that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: citation: "E.g. for this question, I voted to close" - it was intended to be a demo close vote

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. I've seen many cases where the person to whom the comment is attibuted doesn't actually agree with it, or has changed his mind, or ... yet unless they see and act on it, the comment is there for all time with their name. Not appropriate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this is by-design. You can also edit it if you wish; it's your comment, posted on your behalf by the system.

I would hope you would use this power judiciously, but if you choose to delete these comments as a matter of course then there's minimal harm; your vote remains unless you retract it, and will be reviewed by other voters in the normal fashion.

Comment: Side note: I'd advice not to edit "duplicate" comments - it is very hard to convince system to not auto-remove them when question is actually closed as duplicate and all manual edits are lost. If you have something to say in addition to duplicate - consider separate comment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Do you feel the same even if it's edited to *"You can achieve the same thing by using Foo class instead, [like in this answer]."* In other words, adding context to a not entirely clear duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it does sound like a problem with the auto-delete mechanism that would lead to editing comments being, on average, useless?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan the auto-remove duplicate comments function has had a lot of "features", at one point it even removed all comments linking to _any_ other question. Leave the auto-generated comment alone and post a new comment if you have anything to add.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I think editing the comment is a great way to explain why the question should be closed.  Just don't write anything you expect to stick around afterwards.

Comment: @SuperScript many people get a bit unhappy about "this (censored) system just deleted my comment automatically without any reasons or notifications"... You are definitely welcome to edit the "duplicate" comment but I see no reason to recommend it to anyone else.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan If you want to add context to explain why you chose that duplicate, isn't that information that you want to stick around after it gets closed? Especially if it gets closed before the OP comes back and sees your comment.

Comment: E.g., the net is: If you have something more to say that only needs to be there *until* the question is closed, edit; it will stay until auto-removed when the question is closed. If it should be there *after* (for instance, to help point out how it's a duplicate, for others in the future), post separately.

Comment: Y'all have now put 100x more thought into this than anyone, ever. T.J. sums it up nicely though.